# How to include a template from parent directory in twig

Tags: php, twig

i'm currently in views/pages/edit.twig file and want to include a file from upper directory.
in php normally you would do

```
include '../file.php';
```

but i failed to get the file with twig.
I'm not using Symfony, using only twig templating engine so no bundles etc.

```
{ include '../common/file.twig' }
```

dots are not recognized as command in twig and i dont know how to get there.
i dont want to extend anything just include some basic file with some text in it

Comment: Just use `views/common/file.twig`

Comment: This is my problem too . how can I load it , @DarkBee your solution did not worked for me

Comment: @JoeshRazor You add more directories in twig by calling `$twig->addPath($folder);`, thus making twig to look in those folders as well. Perhaps this could help you

Comment: thank you @DarkBee , I solve my problem , it was my mistake to adding full path

Answer (score 0):

Visibly Twig doesn't recognise / use relative paths with '../' in Symfony 5.4.

The way to link to a template that is in another folder is to use the path to that folder starting from the templates folder.

So, for example :

```
templates
├─ homepage
├─ general
│  ├─ header.twig
│  ├─ main.html
│  └─ footer.twig
└─ menu
   ├─ menu_app.twig
   └─ menu_homepage.twig
```

In header.twig, you need to link to menu_app.twig in this way :
`menu/menu_app.twig`.

Of course if it is a subfolder of your current folder no need to use the absolute from template path.

If your template path is outside of the template root directory, you have to register that path in `twig.yaml` and create a template namespace : [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/templates.html#template-namespaces)

Hope it helps !