# Including twig files from current directory

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using symfony 3.1 in our project. Currently I have a need of dynamically loading the twig files. Now i am stuck in an issue.

I am trying to include some twig files from another twig file. But the catch is that I cannot specify the full path of the template files, it should be loaded by the relative path. I will explain with an example

My current code is

In **website:SpaceFantasy:Article:details.html.twig** I have

```
{% block templateblock %}
    {% include 'website:SpaceFantasy:Article:templateDetail.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'website:SpaceFantasy:Article:templateImage.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'website:SpaceFantasy:Article:templateComments.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

This will work correctly, but I want to remove the `website:SpaceFantasy:Article:` part from the include file, so that the file will be loaded from the current twig directory. like below

```
{% block templateblock %}
    {% include 'templateDetail.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'templateImage.html.twig' %}
    {% include 'templateComments.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is it possible to configure it like that?

Comment: Yes, its possible to directly use twig file instead of full path, If its in same directory...

Answer (score 4):

I understand why you'd like to do that but you can't. The `include` is based on absolute path of views (`.../views/`).

So yes, of course if you place the template in `app/Resources/views` will work, but this is not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Just place your template in **app/Resources/view**

then you could include by

```
{% include 'templateDetail.html.twig' %}
```

or

```
{% include '::templateDetail.html.twig' %}
```

if it's inside a folder

```
{% include 'folderName/templateDetail.html.twig' %}
```

Read more

- [Symfony Template Locations](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations)
- [Symfony Including other Templates](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/templating.html#including-other-templates)

Answer (score 1):

I posted an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677308/how-to-include-a-template-from-parent-directory-in-twig/71825037#71825037)

Basically, in Symfony 5.4, you can't use "../" but you have to use the absolute path from the template root directory as such : `path/to/template`, with 'path' being a subfolder of the first sublevel of the templates folder.

If you need to give the path to a template that is outside of the templates folder, you have to add a reference to it in `twig.yaml`.